# How to estimate green or yellow based on the output of RCCC CMOS image sensor

Tags: ccd, colour

RCCC is a kind of color filter array with one Red filter and three Clear filters, which means it only outputs red color or monochrome signal ([Interfacing Red/Clear Sensors](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/EE358.pdf) )

[image: RCCC Color filter]

I know that some RCCC cameras can output coloured images. This must be down be via **color mixture technology**. Unluckily, I am totally new to this area. Are there any suggestions for me to start to mix the output of RCCC sensors? To be specific, I want to estimate the yellow or green color.

Comment: Using CIE color models and data is one of the things I do for work. These models use three separate integral results for the standard color receptor responses, which are then combined to form a two-coordinate point, combined with an assumed white-point (like D60), in order to construct a vector directed towards a curve used estimate a color hue as it might be perceived. Without even knowing the calibrated responses of your red filters, let alone the clear ones, or how each pixel integrates that band of wavelengths, at best you could very grossly subtract an unknown to get a different unknown.

Comment: @jonk, thank you for your reply! Can you provide some tutorials for me? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know of any "tutorials." Just textbooks and reference books (and my work products.)

Comment: @jonk, could you please give some information about textbooks or reference books? I am new to this area

Comment: Well, the one I started with is called, "Measuring Color," 2nd edition, by R. W. G. Hunt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all.

To cite the paragraph just above the figure you took from the document you linked to (emphasis by me):

> One of the
>   key color information is the *red channel*, which
>   will help localize the region of interest (ROI) … .
>   For example, Traffic Sign Recognition (TSR)
>   applications can identify possible locations of *red
>   colored* speed limit signs in the captured image.
>
> Hence, the output generated by RCCC
>   sensors is almost as detailed as a monochrome
>   output and still provides the **red color
>   information** as shown in Figure 2.

These cameras simply aren't used for anything but getting an intensity and red-color image!

So, albeit there's info about which pixels are more red than others (at quarter resolution, at least), there's no info on whether pixels are more greenish, yellowish or blueish.

So, without further info coming from other pictures, you can only get a greyscale and a red image, and any combination of these, but since there's no info on anything than overall intensity and red intensity, well, no other color info.

Notice that external info might help here – you might train some [classifier](https://richzhang.github.io/colorization/) on a lot of images, and that classifier would then be able to "guess" colors. But that's no better than looking at a black and white photograph of a tree and saying that the leaves are green (because you know that leaves are always green) – that info doesn't come from the image (and hence might be totally wrong; if you don't know the tree, it might be a tree in autumn foliage in bright yellow color).